# How do large sites do pagination?

Tags: database, pagination, scalability

How do large sites handle pagination on search results so that the nth page loads roughly as quickly as the first? For example, Google, Youtube, Hulu, etc.

Comment: Why would the nth page take any longer to load than the first page? In any case, most sites cache the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube:

> **Sorry, YouTube does not serve more
>   than 1000 results for any query**

so it probably caches the first 1k results in a something similar to a memcached blob.

Hulu: limits to 3000 results.  Probably cached as well.

Google: It's pure black magic.  Keep in mind it uses a lot of distributed computing (and not a simple db lookup), and probably caches the first n results for any query, and also "html ready" results for each result page, and intermediate results (See [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)).

To summarize:  Your first query to any page *might* take more time since it can cause the engine to start a db/distributed search, however, it's results (much more than the amount you will be showed) will probably be kept for a while in a very fast cache for serving any page for the same query without stressing the db again.